Why no Big Bang are happening now?
Why we are not able to see any Big Bang now? There is a possibility, I think.
Is it that Universe is so large that the probability of it's happening in the observable universe is almost zero, or is something else in play?

The big bang happened everywhere all at once.  It wasn't a tiny area in a big empty universe, it was spacetime itself coming into existence.

Maybe it's still going on.

The big bang was not an explosion.
It was the hot, dense state of the universe when it was young.  We do see it! Because light moves at a finite speed, as we look further away, we look further back in time.  If we look at how the universe was 13.7 billion years ago, it looks hot, dense, and very smooth.  There are no stars or galaxies just hot gas,  that gas is the hot, dense gas of the big bang.  We can't look any further back because that gas is opaque.
